# WebApi 404's with Parameters - calling via javascript GET

Tags: javascript, c#, parameters, routes, asp.net-web-api

WebApi Method within LocationsController:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetLocations(int id, long start, long end)
{
return Ok();
}
```

Calls I have tried to make (GET):

```
https://api.com/Locations/GetLocations/34934/1/1
https://api.com/Locations/GetLocations?34934&start=1&end=1
```

As such:

```
factHttp.httpRequest('/locations/GetLocations', 'GET', vm.ID + '/' + start.getTime() + '/' + now.getTime()).then(function (_result) {
                vm.plots = angular.fromJson(_result.data);
            });

var _httpRequest = function requestCall(requestPartURL, requestType, requestPayload) {

            var _resultHttp = $http({
                url: apiURL + requestPartURL,
                method: requestType,
                data: requestPayload,
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN')
                }
            }).success(function (response) {
                console.log("HTTP CALL SUCCESS");
                return {
                    result: 'SUCCESS',
                    resultObj: response,
                    errorCode: '',
                    errorDesc: ''
                }

            }).error(function (response) {
                console.log("HTTP CALL FAIL");
                console.log(response);

                return getErrorObj(response);
            });

            return _resultHttp;

        }
```

Routing:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "IdentWithRange",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{start}/{end}"
        );
```

If I change the web api method to just take (int id) and call GetLocation/34934 it works just fine. What have I done wrong here?

I continually get a 404 error. Some of this was not written by myself (namely the JS stuff as I am bad at it), but it's the first time working with any sort of api for me, where I control both ends, I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Have you tried: `http://api.com/Locations/GetLocations?id=34934&start=1&end=1`?

Comment: Just tried it now, to no avail, unfortunately. It doesn't even hit the method at all, just straight up 404s.

Comment: Just for the fun of it, could you try to rename your `MapHttpRoute` from 'IdentWithRange' to 'DefaultApi'?

Comment: That broke everything in the rest of the API :D

Comment: Ok. I think the problem is your in routing. Assuming you have a 'DefaultApi that looks like this; `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "DefaultAction" });`, could you simply try to remove your 'IdentWithRange'?

Comment: No dice on that one either unfortunately, just a flat out 404. http://puu.sh/lwVhm/c0479e1d8e.png

Comment: Forgot to mention, use `http://api.com/Locations/GetLocations?id=34934&start=1&end=1` when trying the `DefaultApi` mentioned above.

Comment: Normally it is not necessary to add special routing for handling multiple parameters

Comment: The default route for webAPI begins with "api", add that to your route like this: https://api.com/api/Locations/GetLocations/34934/1/1 I would also recommend adding [HttpGet, Route("yourRouteHere")]

Answer (score 1):

The routing record you created would be looking for the following route

```
/api/controller/id/start/end
```

but you are trying to pass in parameters, not specify a route. 
 You dont need a special routing record to handling multiple parameters. Using a 'standard' routing record will suffice.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new 
{ 
  id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "DefaultAction" 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you need to add "api" to your route.

```
https://api.com/api/Locations/GetLocations/34934/1/1
```

Recommended:

```
https://api.com/api/locations/34934/1/1

[HttpGet, Route("locations/{id:int:min(1)}/{start:long}/{end:long}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetLocations(int id, long start, long end)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: I changed it first to what you showed at the top, then again to what you show at the bottom, leaving out the action part. I still get 404'd and can't figure out why http://puu.sh/lx4Fx/e172d36edc.png

Comment: In your image you are not passing the id's. So it will not be able to find your route.

Comment: This is perhaps something wrong in the javascript then, I'm not used to it at all so I'll try and figure out some more.

Comment: $http.get('https://api.com/api/locations/getvehiclelocations/' +     vm.selectedVehicleId + '/' + start.getTime() + '/' + now.getTime(), {
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN')
                    }
                });

This returns a 404 for me as well: http://puu.sh/lx9zg/8989dbfa8d.png

Comment: Your calling "getvehiclelocations" but your route is "getlocations".

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo as I'd changed both around to try and get it working, it is GetLocations again, I just hadn't amended it properly.